# Using nightwatch compare arrays of elements to see if values match

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

For every image on the page I create a wrapping anchor around it using js so I want to write a test to ensure it is there.

Using nightwatch I am attempting a test to ensure that every image has the parent anchor.

I have been attempting this test using three different methods.

1. Test whether every images parent is an anchor
2. Test whether every anchors child is an image
3. Gather an array of all the images and an array of all the anchors an compare there lengths

I couldn't figure out a way on how to accomplish the first two so I have been attempting the third as it seemed to make the most sense however I am having trouble creating the two arrays of elements to compare.

I have been trying variations of the below code in attempt to get an array of both the elements or there elementIDs so I can compare them but have had little success

If anyone has some suggestions on how to achieve this I am all ears. Also open to scrapping my third approach if the first two are more plausible.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Here is what I have been trying:

**html after JavaScript has wrapped the images**

```
<figure class="figure-image">
    <a role="button">
        <img src="image-source" alt="image-alt" />
    </a>
</figure>

<figure class="figure-image">
    <a role="button">
        <img src="image-source" alt="image-alt" />
    </a>
</figure>

<figure class="figure-image">
    <a role="button">
        <img src="image-source" alt="image-alt" />
    </a>
</figure>

<figure class="figure-image">
    <a role="button">
        <img src="image-source" alt="image-alt" />
    </a>
</figure>

**Image Tests**

// Both anchor.length and image.length are 0 so of course the tests pass
'Anchors will be created for each image found': browser => {
    browser.elements('css selector', '.figure-image', elem => {
      // return elem.value
      elem.value.map(figure => {
        const anchors = browser.elementIdElements(figure.ELEMENT, 'tag name', 'a', anchor => { return anchor.value })
        const images = browser.elementIdElements(figure.ELEMENT, 'tag name', 'img', image => { return image.value })
        browser.assert.equal(anchors.length, images.length, 'Anchors match the amount of images')
      })
    })
  }


// Each anchors and images are just an object of nightwatch api commands when I log them out
'Anchors will be created for each image found': browser => {
    const anchors = browser.elements('css selector', '.figure-image > a', elem => {
      return elem.value
    })

    const images = browser.elements('css selector', '.figure-image > a > img', elem => {
      return elem.value
    })

    browser.assert.equal(anchors.length, images.length, 'Anchors match the amount of images')
  }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use CSS `:nth-child()` and assert their presence?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @king_wayne I am not sure I follow. Do you think you could provide an example? I would have to know exactly how many anchors and images there were with :nth child wouldn't I. This number changes from page to page which is why I am trying to grab them via browser.elements().

Comment: I was thinking something like this may work for you: 
`browser.expect.element('img:nth-child(1) > a').to.be.present`

Comment: or maybe you could even throw those assertions into a `for` loop and use the loop iteration as the value of the `:nth-child(x)` if you already know how many of the image elements you will have.  If you don't know how many image elements you'll have beforehand then you could use `getElements` number of elements as the `for` loop value